# Parsing Reviews in Hindi or Marathi Using HTMLAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a C# project that involves parsing and extracting data from HTML documents. I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack library to handle HTML parsing, and I've encountered a challenge when it comes to selecting specific elements from the HTML content.

Here is a brief summary of the problem:
The issue is that when the data is in English, the code works fine. However, when the data is in languages like Marathi or Hindi (obtained from Amazon reviews for a product), I encounter difficulties. The extracted text appears as encoded values, making it challenging to work with the content effectively.

I've attempted to address this issue by setting the encoding to UTF-8, but it hasn't resolved the problem. I also tried using doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes, but I still can't obtain the expected string as InnerText.

I'm seeking guidance and solutions on how to correctly handle and parse user reviews written in Indian languages using HTMLAgilityPack in C#. Any assistance or insights into character encoding and text extraction for such languages would be greatly appreciated.

This revised paragraph provides a clear and detailed overview of your issue, making it easier for others to understand and offer potential solutions on platforms like Stack Overflow.

[image: image- getting encoded values]
[image: code]

My expected output should be the exact, human-readable text of the reviews written in Indian languages like Marathi and Hindi. Instead of seeing garbled or encoded values,i want extract the original text of the reviews in a format that is understandable and can be processed as needed within my C# project.

In essence, the goal is to successfully extract the user reviews written in Indian languages without any encoding.

Comment: The image with the output you are seeing is ok. But do not post images of code. Add code as text (formatted as code).

Comment: Post code and examples and a *clear* explanation of the problem, not screenshots. C# strings are Unicode and Amazon pages are already UTF8, like almost every single web page. Trying to "fix" the encoding will only *cause* problems, by mangling the text

Comment: At the very least, post a URL, your code, what you expected and what you got. It's far more likely that you used a wrong selector or that the page doesn't have the structure you assume.

Comment: If you save that text as-is into a text file and then open it with an editor that is using **a font** that is capable of displaying the respective unicode glyphs, is it still broken?

Comment: Sitenote: Data-Scraping is prohibited in the Amazon ToS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.